# Sync Framework Compatible with Server 2012 R2

Tags: compatibility, microsoft-sync-framework, windows-server-2012-r2

I have been looking all over the Internet for the answer to my question, and I have no found a definitive answer.

Is the Microsoft Sync Framework compatible with Windows Server 2012 R2?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to this question while further researching this topic.

It appears that Microsoft Sync Framework is not supported for Windows Server 2012.  See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc761704%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)